# Random walk with absorbing barriers: total probability of absorpion

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a random walk that moves up by 1 unit with probability $p$ and down by one unit with probability $1-p$. It starts at $0$ and there is one absorbing bareer at $-2$. How can I calculate the probability that the random walk is absorbed in at most $n$ steps?